# Android radiogroup, divider between radiobuttons

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, divider

Is there a simple way to add a divider between `RadioButtons` inside a `RadioGroup`? I've tried using the `divider` xml attribute and it doesn't seem to be working. In case it's relevant, the `RadioGroup` in my layout does not contain any child views; I'm adding the `RadioButtons` programmatically.

**EDIT**: Problem solved. You can add views besides `RadioButton` inside `RadioGroup` in the xml. In my case, you can also do it programmatically, but be careful about your layout params. Akki had the right idea, and this worked for me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        // add a divider with height of 1 pixel
        View v = new View(this);
        v.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
        v.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.darker_gray);
        mRadioGroup.addView(v);
    }
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
    /* set other properties ... */

    mRadioGroup.addView(rb);
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful if you could provide an image of what you're trying to make.

Comment: radio group is derived from linear layout so create a view object and add it after each radio button except last one.

Comment: mtmurdock: I just need a thin horizontal line between each item.

Akki: I thought of that, but was hoping there was something simpler. It seems like such a fairly obvious use case that one would expect Google to have made provisions for it within the framework.

Answer (score 37):

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/location_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">
</RadioGroup>
```

That will work for you. And I am really curious how you add view into Group View? That should cause classcastexception, no ?

Comment: This does not work for me.  It has no effect.  But if I define and assign my own shape for android:divider for the RadioGroup (not the individual buttons) in an xml file, it works.  Anyone know why?

Comment: (Btw, this didn't work for me, until I added an orientation vertical to my RadioGroup)

Answer (score 17):

Here's a workaround:

First create a **Shape Drawable** as your divider. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid 
    android:color="@color/white" />
<stroke 
    android:width="0.3dp" 
    android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

This is just a simple black border. Put it inside your drawable/ folder and name it something like **custom_divider.xml**.

Then, go to your layout which uses a **RadioGroup**. Use the ShapeDrawable as a background for each of the **RadioButton**(s). Here is an example:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:divider="@color/black" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radiogroup_divider"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radiogroup_divider"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_radiogroup_divider"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

You can also add a ShapeDrawable to your RadioGroup. It depends on you, customize it if you need. :)

Here is my example of a RadioGroup with custom border (with corner radius) and custom divider ShapeDrawable(s).
[image: RadioGroup divider]

Answer (score 7):

Create shape drawable that represents divider (Called "radio_group_divider"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="12dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Use this drawable as "divider" in the RadioGroup:

```
<RadioGroup
        ...
        android:divider="@drawable/radio_group_divider"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        ...>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create RadioGroup programmatically, then you have to set dividers programmatically too. You can do it like that:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getActivity()); //We create a new radio group
radioGroup.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
radioGroup.setDividerDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.divider_horizontal_textfield, getActivity().getTheme()));
```

...

**Note:** This code part is working in a fragment. So if you want to put it in to an activity, you have to modify by changing "getActivity()" with "YourActivityName.this"