# Radiobutton drawable not reacting to state_checked

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, android-drawable

I am trying to create a check-mark in a `RadioButton`that disappears if that button is not selected. However, the custom check-mark only seems to react to `state_checked` if I put it in the `android:button` attribute of `RadioButton`. This is unexpected, because if I replace the custom check-mark by `android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"`, this works perfectly fine. Including the check-mark in `drawableRight` has my preference since setting the spacing on the `android:button` attribute is problematic.

Are there different settings that will make the check-mark behave as expected?

This is the current code:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/period_selector"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
            android:text="@string/period_selection_month"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?divider" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/period_selector"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
            android:text="@string/period_selection_year"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

with `drawable/period_selector.xml` as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

To summarize:

- A custom check-mark in `drawableRight` does not render, regardless of whether the button is checked.
- Using the standard `listChoiceIndicatorSingle` in `drawableRight` does correctly respond to whether the button is selected
- Using the custom check-mark in `button` does show the expected selection behavior of appearing and disappearing, but does not listen to spacing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

> `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check" android:state_checked="true" /> </selector>`

Your selector misses the unchecked state of the `RadioButton`, and therefore it sets the `drawableRight` to have no drawable. So, the default occupied size for the `drawableRight` is 0.

When you change the button state to be checked; it tries to draw the `ic_check` to currently reserved size of the `drawableRight` which is 0; and hence you'd see nothing changed.

**Solution**

To fix this, you need to specify the unchecked state of the selector to some drawable.

> My trials to use `@null` or to using 0 size, but both fails with
> exceptions as the drawable is not specified or it's 0 in size.

So, the one that fixed that is to use the same drawable as `ic_check` but with a transparent current.

This is the default check mark drawable provided by Android Studio:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="@color/teal_700"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/teal_700"
        android:pathData="M9,16.17L4.83,12l-1.42,1.41L9,19 21,7l-1.41,-1.41z" 

</vector>
```

Then create another typical one with a transparent color instead: **ic_check_empty.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="@android:color/transparent">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:pathData="M9,16.17L4.83,12l-1.42,1.41L9,19 21,7l-1.41,-1.41z"/>
</vector>
```

And apply that to the selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_empty" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

[image]

**Side Note:** Using a `View` within a `RadioGroup` will raise an exception as it's not allowed here; if you need to add a separator between the RadionButtons, then you can use:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">
```

Or you can have a look [here for other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706013/android-radiogroup-divider-between-radiobuttons).